# YouTube API Uploads via CORS

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, cors

I am trying to use the [sample code provided by Google](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fyt-upload-javascript) to complete uploads to YouTube via CORS.  For now I would like to test this on my localhost.

[Demo](https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html)

On my localhost when I click the "sign-in" button it asks me to sign-in to a Google account, requests permission for the app and then closes the modal.

I think the issue has something to do with the redirect URI.  I have created the app in the Google console, named it etc. The URI I am trying is: `http://localhost/PATH/TO/Uploader/index.html`.  I have also tried `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/PATH/TO/Uploader/`.

Looking at `index.js` I can tell that `oauth2Callback` is not firing, which is why I think its a URI issue.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.  I ended up re-copying the `index.html` file from the sample code and now its working.  Looks like somehow I accidentally removed `data-callback="oauth2Callback"` in this span:

```
  <span
      class="g-signin"
      data-callback="oauth2Callback"
      data-clientid="661613006473-qmbp8lmrjg79a7ch5ghbvhqf2106o89b.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload">
  </span>
```